# Cannot find entry file index.android.js even using 0.48.2 react native version

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native version 0.48.2 . The simple react native application works fine and successfully deployed at my physical device but when I add `yarn add react-native-navigation@latest` and followed the process from https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android it started giving me the following error [cannot find entry file index.android.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vwcS.jpg)

```
{
  "name": "newreact",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
   "scripts": {
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"test": "jest"
},
 "dependencies": {
 "react": "16.2.0",
 "react-native": "^0.48.2",
 "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.336"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-jest": "22.0.4",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
"jest": "22.0.5",
"react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
```

}

TIA

Comment: First of all, check manually `index.android.js` is present or not in your `App Folder`

Comment: In versions greater then 0.43 , index.android.js and index.ios.js has been combined to form index.js .

Comment: Just went through the setup steps that you linked on an empty project created with `react-native init --version="0.48.2"` and everything built correctly and deployed. Blank screen since I have no other code, but I didn't get that error. Do as the others suggested and check the contents of your project folder and maybe even post your `package.json` file just in case.

Comment: @MichaelCheng  package.json has been updated . Kindly check

Comment: @ZainAfzal Odd, did you downgrade the project from a later version? Your react dependency is 16.2.0 where as mine is 16.0.0-alpha.12. React Native always tracks the latest version of React and since the only version released after react v16.2.0 is react-native v0.52.0, it seems that you created it and later tried to downgrade it. Depending on what you did to try and downgrade, chances are that you simply do not have an `index.android.js` or an `index.ios.js` file as those have since been removed in later releases. Do as @Heisen-Burg suggests and check that those files actually exist.

Comment: Yes i did downgraded react native as react-native navigation did not quite worked out with 0.52 version . There were compilation error in it and I was told to downgrade it to 0.48 , I did that. But came up with this error and just couldnt find out a way out of it

Comment: @ZainAfzal Then it's as I said. You don't have those files and whatever method you used for downgrading probably wasn't fully correct. For the sake of answering this question, do an `ls` on your project directory and post the files/folders inside of it.